# how do matlab do the sort?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

How is the sort() working in matlab?
Code in pure matlab:
q is an array:

```
q = -0.2461    2.9531  -15.8867   49.8750  -99.1172  125.8438  -99.1172   
49.8750  -15.8867    2.9531   -0.2461
```

After `q = sort(roots(q))`, I got:

    `q = 0.3525 
       0.3371 - 0.1564i
       0.3371 + 0.1564i
       0.2694 - 0.3547i
       0.2694 + 0.3547i
       1.3579 - 1.7880i
       1.3579 + 1.7880i
   2.4410 - 1.1324i
   2.4410 + 1.1324i
   2.8365`

Well, seems to work fine! Then in python, I use (q is the same as above, it is an `np.array`):

```
import numpy as np
q = np.sort(np.roots(q))
```

And I got:

```
[ 0.26937874-0.35469815j  0.26937874+0.35469815j  0.33711562-0.15638427j
 0.33711562+0.15638427j  0.35254298+0.j          1.35792218-1.78801226j
 1.35792218+1.78801226j  2.44104520-1.13237431j  2.44104520+1.13237431j
 2.83653354+0.j        ]
```

Well... These two results seem different in that they sort differently, so what are the reasons? did I make something wrong? thank you in advance!

My answer:

```
def sortComplex(complexList):
    complexList.sort(key=abs)
    # then sort by the angles, swap those in descending orders
    return complexList
```

Then call it in the python code, works fine :p

Comment: try `roots(q)[ abs(roots(q)).argsort() ]`

Comment: I just tried it.. (of course you need to import the proper modules)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the MATLAB documentation for [SORT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sort.html):

> If `A` has complex entries `r` and `s`,
>   `sort` orders them according to the
>   following rule: `r` appears before `s` in
>   `sort(A)` if either of the following
>   hold:
>
> - `abs(r) < abs(s)`
> - `abs(r) = abs(s)` and `angle(r) < angle(s)`

In other words, an array that has complex entries is first sorted based on the [absolute value](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/abs.html) (i.e. complex magnitude) of those entries, and any entries that have the same absolute value are sorted based on their [phase angles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/angle.html).

Python (i.e. numpy) orders things differently. From [the documentation Amro linked to in his comment](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html):

> The sort order for complex numbers is
>   lexicographic. If both the real and
>   imaginary parts are non-nan then the
>   order is determined by the real parts
>   except when they are equal, in which
>   case the order is determined by the
>   imaginary parts.

In other words, an array that has complex entries is first sorted based on the real component of the entries, and any entries that have equal real components are sorted based on their imaginary components.

**EDIT:**

If you want to reproduce the numpy behavior in MATLAB, one way you can do it is to use the function [SORTROWS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sortrows.html) to create a sort index based on the [real](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/real.html) and [imaginary](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imag.html) components of the array entries, then apply that sort index to your array of complex values:

```
>> r = roots(q);  %# Compute your roots
>> [junk,index] = sortrows([real(r) imag(r)],[1 2]);  %# Sort based on real,
                                                      %#   then imaginary parts
>> r = r(index)  %# Apply the sort index to r

r =

   0.2694 - 0.3547i
   0.2694 + 0.3547i
   0.3369 - 0.1564i
   0.3369 + 0.1564i
   0.3528          
   1.3579 - 1.7879i
   1.3579 + 1.7879i
   2.4419 - 1.1332i
   2.4419 + 1.1332i
   2.8344
```

Comment: @gnovice: aha, I got it, but np.sort(), wasn't it the same as the sort() in matlab? your answer is the doc for matlab sort, I am not sure what the np.sort() works?

Comment: "The sort order for complex numbers is lexicographic. [...]": http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html

Comment: @gnoivce: Okay, I see, thanks, so does that mean I have to write a new sort() for the same purpose as that in matlab?? or is there another function I could call directly with numpy??

Comment: @serina: I updated my answer to show you one way to reproduce the numpy behavior in MATLAB.